# Voltage drop across resistor

Tags: voltage, kirchhoffs-laws

To find the potential difference between the points A and B:
On applying KVL between A and B, why we do not consider the voltage drop across the 10ohm resistor?
[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: Can you draw a current loop that goes from positive to negative of the same battery that goes through the 10 ohm resistor in one direction only? So what is the net current through the 10 ohms?

Answer (score 2):

From Kirchhoff's current law, we know the current through the 10-ohm resistor is 0. Therefore we know the voltage across it is also 0.